# Como validar modal con inputs vacíos en Materialize

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

Buenos días, estoy trabajando con **Materialize** y estoy usando una ventana modal, pero dentro del modal tengo un input y quisiera validarlo en caso de que el input este vacío, no se cierre automáticamente. tengo esta modal y cada vez que doy clic en guardar la modal se cierra sin importar si el campo está lleno o vacío.
Agradecería mucho que me puedan orientar como debo trabajar en esa parte para poder validar y el formulario no se cierre automáticamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4):

Para hacer lo que quieres tienes que manejar los eventos con jquery, por ejemplo:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<body>
<!-- Modal Trigger -->
  <a id="op" class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>

  <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <input type="text" id="example" class="validate" required>
        <label for="example">Example</label
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Cerrar sin validar</a>
      <a href="#!" id="cl"class="modal-action waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Validar y Cerrar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#op").click(function(){
      $('#modal1').openModal();
    });
      
    
    $( "#cl" ).click(function() {
       if($("#example").val() === ""){
         alert("Rellene todos los campos");
       }else{
         $('#modal1').closeModal();
       }
      
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
```

En el código anterior lo principal es:

```
<a href="#!" id="cl"class="modal-action waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Validar y Cerrar</a>
```

En class quitamos `modal-close` para que no cierre el modal al darle click, luego con el `id="cl"` manejamos el evento click con jquery para realizar la validación.

Es algo básico, pero espero te sirva.